# Change file type to always launch new program instance?

Tags: windows, file-association

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run multiple instance of any windows application](https://superuser.com/questions/165937/run-multiple-instance-of-any-windows-application)

I have a file type associated with a certain program.  The problem is when I already have one of these files open, and I double click on another one in Windows Explorer, it launches in the program that is already open.  I want it to launch a new window, a totally separate instance of the program.  How is this achieved?

Comment: That depends a lot on the particular program. It will probably have to have a command-line option or some configuration option to enable that.

Comment: @Dennis I figured so, but I assume there is some sort of standard in place for this?  Does Windows have a predictable command-line switch for this?

Comment: I think if you use the `RUNAS` command, that will do it in its own instance, but you need to test this theory.

Comment: @Don't make me laugh! ;) Seriously, though, the Windows API has features to control multiple instances, but it's up to the individual program as to how or if they make use of it or pass the configuration of it to the user.

Comment: I wonder what this secret "certain program" is?

Comment: @Moab Doesn't matter.  It could be *any* program.

Comment: @Josh actually it does, some programs have this functionality, some don't. If we knew what the program was someone could post an Answer instead of a bunch of comments.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the program is.  There are no options within the program to control this.  I need to control this from Windows and I think that's a reasonable request.

Comment: It's not reasonable for the OS to mandate how programs conduct their own business. "One application only" or "One application per document" is the program's own business.

Comment: It used to behave the way I want it to; I know this is possible! Could you negative Nancys bug off already?