# How can I launch single instanced applications multiple times on the same machine without VMWare?

Tags: windows-8, multiple-instances, application-launch

I have a game in which I want to test how many players are able to join a multiplayer game - the problem is that my VMWare machines return "Graphics Hardware not supported on this platform" when I try to run the application.

I tried launching it with different user credentials but it somehow keeps me from runing it twice, what can you guys recommend?

It's specifically: Mercenaries 2

Also:

- making multiple copies of the .exe then trying to run them separatly doesn't work.
- launching one instance as administrator and the other one as user (or vice versa) doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried sandboxie?  Put each instance in a separate sandbox.

Comment: I will try it, I have requested a key for one day (now I need to wait for a reply.. multiple sandboxes are only supported in the registered version)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run multiple instance of any windows application](http://superuser.com/questions/165937/run-multiple-instance-of-any-windows-application)