# How to run multiple instance of the same application in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, privacy

I don't want to use sandbox or virtual box because they are not considered smooth integration. I've also tried using bat, shift click, "multi" command but none of them work. The application will return an error message saying "XXX is already running".

I guess that there is a check of the same process. How to block this kind of checks or run my secondary instance in stealth?

---

Edit: the application I am interested is G-suite file stream. I have two G-suite account one with a school and one with a company; I need to switch between these two if I cannot run two file-stream application at the same time.

Comment: What is the application? Not all applications can run multiple instances. I did take note of your restrictions, but you can run another instance in a VMware Virtual machine and use Unity mode so that the integration is quite smooth.

Comment: @John Thank you for the tip! I've heard that the windows sandbox intelligently distributes its resources. Is it true? How does it compare with the Unity mode of VMware?

Comment: Sandbox does not have a Unity mode like VMware. Sandbox machines go away when Sandbox is closed. VMware machines are permanent.

Comment: @John I'll give a try!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there may be some help on this previously asked question: [Run multiple instance of any windows application](https://superuser.com/questions/165937/run-multiple-instance-of-any-windows-application)

Looks like [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) might help to view, kill, and create new instances.