# Always launch new instance of Word when opening file

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, multiple-instances

I have a Word document. I open it by double-clicking its icon. But if the file is already open in Word, double-clicking again on its icon simply moves the already-open window containing the document to the foreground. I want double-clicking on the icon a second time to instead open a second window.

In other words, I would like to open multiple Word windows, each displaying my document, by double-clicking multiple times on the document's icon. How may I do this?

(From within Word, it's easy to open additional windows for the same document via View > New Window. But that isn't satisfactory for my purposes.)

A few posts here are related to my question. [This one](https://superuser.com/questions/165937/run-multiple-instance-of-any-windows-application) is an example. But the general advice is that solutions to this problem are application-specific, and no one seems to have asked how to solve the problem for Word.

*Potential solution: shortcuts and command-line arguments.* I can create and edit a shortcut to the document. And if I do so, I can pass command-line arguments to Word. I'd hoped that Word has an argument that means "open this document in a new instance of Word," but I haven't yet found anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the answer from George 123345 in this article [Always Open New Instance of Word](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/617ba008-79a2-46b8-92c2-1cd0f65a6299/always-open-new-instance-of-word).

1.Open Registry editor and go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell.

2.Right click "ImmersiveShell", and create a new key called "Launcher".

3.At HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\Launcher, right click in the right pane and create a new DWORD value called DesktopAppsAlwaysLaunchNewInstance.

4.Double click it and set its value to 1.

Comment: Thank you, Ceasar. What is the article by "George 12345" that you mentioned?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought I added a link to the article (but it didn't), now I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install SandBoxie Plus
2. Open SandBoxie Plus
3. Right Click DefaultBox
4. Run
5. Run Program
6. Add Word.exe Path, OK
7. Right Click Word.exe in SandBoxie
8. Create and Save Shortcut

For Multiple Instances Create New Boxes and repeat process

Comment: Are you associated with SandBoxie ?

Comment: No, I just found out about it because I needed something like this as well.